# How to replace specific text by some visually specific entity in UITextView (like Xcode placeholders)

Tags: swift, uitextview, core-text, nstextstorage, nstextcontainer

I know the title can be unclear, it's just because I don't know how to explain it better...

So here's what I try to achieve: I would like my user to type into a `UITextView` and, like in Xcode, if some pattern is detected, for instance `<#TAG#>`, display just the word `TAG` with a specific rounded cornered background color, and the user can only select the full word... Bonus, I would like to add a small SF Symbol before, that would be lovely.

So I've seen many tutorials with `NSTextContainer` and `NSTextLayoutManager` but what I've seen so far only permits me to change the color or the background of the whole `<#TAG#>` not replace by the word itself, nor prevent the user from selecting a part of it...

So if someone can point me in the good direction...

[image: Example of <#TAG#> in Xcode]

PS: Of course, I need the text to keep the whole `<#TAG#>`, not to simply replace it by TAG.

PPS: It needs to work on iOS 15+

Comment: You need to learn about Text Kit. You will need to take control of glyph drawing. Watch the WWDC 2021 video about it.

Comment: Take a look at this syntax text editor which has "placeholder" feature.
https://github.com/twostras/Sourceful

Comment: Thank you (the correct link is : https://github.com/twostraws/Sourceful) I will check it out.